# postgres 9.1 logfile change

Tags: postgresql, logging, ubuntu

I have a standard Ubuntu postgres9.1 install running continuosly, I may not stop it.

Nothing has been specifically configured regarding the logging target,
so there is a (rotating somehow) 
logfile /var/log/postgresqlpostgresql-9.1-main.log.
I suppose, it grabs the standard output of the processes.

What I want is to configure a different file target, and, without restart,
(Sorry, no collector, no syslog ... those need restarting)
but with reconfig, the new child processes used that file.

Is that possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified my previous answer because as Daniel Vérité pointed out, you can't set the log file without using the `logging_collector`, the `log_filename` option will be ignored.

Rotation is done through "copy-truncate".  That is logrotate makes a copy of the file and then empties the main log file.

In this case I think you will be lucky in that the server opens up a file handle to the log and uses just that one to write to. This means that you can simply rename the file `mv old_name.log new_name.log`.  The file handle that postgresql uses is bound to the file itself and not the name.

This solution does come with the problem that *when* the server is restarted, it will create a new log file under the old name. You will need to make configuration changes so that when it restarts it continues to write to the same place.

Comment: Hello Couling, thank you for your answer.  To describe the situation in depth, my task is to set the logging very verbose for some days, than back then. The partition doesn't have enough space for the verbose log. It has enough space for the normal logging, with rotated files. So I have to redirect the logfile somehow.

Comment: Secondly, if I set the `log_filename` only, and to a relative filename, it really does something (on a test install make I this research). Namely, no logging then. So I think, setting the `log_filename` only really has some (buggy) effect. I have begun to debug the `pg_ctlcluster`

Comment: the log_filename is officially for the logging collector.  It sounds as though you need to make use of the logging collector or perhaps push logging through syslog.  This will require you to restart the server to enable, but wont require you to restart every time you subsequently change the logging directory.  If you go for the syslog option then you will need to read up on rsyslog

Comment: Yes, I do will use rsyslog next. But currently 600+ processes use that damned output file (fuser). And I should have to be able to redirect the new processes' output to a new one. I may have to give up my idea however, although it sounds me to be a very natural usage. So I'm disappointed a little bit.

Comment: "Rotation is done through "copy-truncate". That is logrotate makes a copy of the file and then empties the main log file.". Thank you for the idea. I did it. I copied the file periodically, then echo "" > file. Some rows may have been lost, but for statistical analysis the result will be fine.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is relatively simple.  Sadly it does require the use of the logging collector which would require a restart to enable.  Without that you can't move a log between partitions.

You can configure which log is used in: 
`/etc/postgresql/<version>/<cluster>/postgresql.conf`

`log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log`

Once you change this, you will need to do a `service postgresql reload` to get it to pick up the changes.

Perhaps I should be clear here, that the point of this answer is that you can use `service postgresql reload` without restarting the server.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would be considered restarting... Unless he meant he can't restart the SYSTEM. I understood that to mean he couldn't restart postgres.

Comment: Hmmm, going to re-check the documentation. I thought the whole point of reload was that it's NOT a restart? It just signals the binary to reload it's configuration.  ... And checking this on my server it doesn't drop the clients. So NO reload is NOT restart.

Comment: If `logging_collector` is disabled and can't be changed as mentioned in the question, `log_filename` is going to be ignored.

Comment: "If logging_collector is disabled ... log_filename is going to be ignored"  
  No, it is not ignored. When I restart (the dev system) it has it's effect: Nothing to log nowhere. (Of course, I won't restart the real server... After `reload`, I'd like to see the -new processes- on the new logfile.